# PyGame MP3 won't play

Tags: python, mp3, pygame

I'm using the code:

```
import pygame, sys, datetime
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen.fill((0, 0, 0, 255))
pygame.display.set_caption("TESTIFICATE")
if datetime.date.today().month == 12 and datetime.date.today().day == 25:
    pygame.mixer.music.load("8bit-jingle-twist.mp3")
    print("Merry Christmas!")
else:
    pygame.mixer.music.load("timeless-mountains.mp3")
print("Loading Music...")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
print("Playing Background Music...")
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Both `8bit-jingle-twist.mp3` and `timeless-mountains.mp3` exist and can be played by VLC. My volume *is* on, as is my confusion.

Comment: I might suggest using the plain mixer.Sound to play music.  It works just as well.  Also consider playing with pygame.mixer.pre_init.

Comment: Did the program raise any exception, or did it just not play sound?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are looking for them in the correct directory?

Try specifying the full path, ie
`"c:/programs/mygame/music/8bit-jingle-twist.mp3"`

Comment: It didn't work, but thanks anyway. Just the black window, but no sound... mute still off...

Answer (score 0):

Very strange, I simply copied your code and just changed the audio files to ones I had, and it worked perfectly fine.

I think therefore it has something to do with the files themselves.

It could be as Hugh Bothwell pointed out, the file path. In which case you could do three things:

Use the whole file path:

`pygame.mixer.music.load("C:/blah/blah/blah/8bit-jingle-twist.mp3")`

Use no file path **(The file must then be in the same folder as the program)**

`pygame.mixer.music.load("8bit-jingle-twist.mp3")`

Or use a one folder jump, where you have a folder inside the same folder as your program.
So for example you have your program in "My Documents", then you make another folder called "Music for Pygame" inside of "My Documents". Then the code would be:

`pygame.mixer.music.load("Music for Pygame/8bit-jingle-twist.mp3")`

I mostly use the last option, so that you can keep your files organized by having a folder for music, a folder for images, etc. and the program would still work if you moved the folder it was in.

Of course it could also be the audio file itself. Make sure it really is a `.mp3` and that it plays fine (VLC is too awesome and can play anything, try playing it on Windows media or something just in case)

Also if using Windows 7 OS, try running it as an administrator and it might fix the problem.

(I ran the code on Windows XP and it worked fine just now)

Comment: I tried all 3 pathing options, and I _may_ have found the problem; On Windows, is `C:\path\file.mp3` the same as `C:/path/file.mp3`? Also, how do I run a python script as admin? I'm used to sudo...

Comment: I use either `C:/path/file.mp3` or `C:\\path\\file.mp3`. since `\` can cause problems.  As for running as admin, I'm not sure.  I think that would be another question, and may have already been asked, take a look around and see what you can find.

Comment: If you're not getting an exception on pygame.mixer.music.load, I doubt that it can't find the files.

Answer (score 0):

**NEW ANSWER:**

if you saved your mp3 file as 'filename.mp3', and you wrote down the .mp3 file extension yourself, then the filename in pygame's pygame.mixer.music.load() function must be written as 'filename.mp3.mp3', because python expects you to add the .mp3. Sometimes the .mp3 is already included in the filename if you manually saved it as that.

Therefore, try this:
`pygame.mixer.music.load('filename.mp3.mp3')`